# div positioning - unable to position multiple div's within existing div

Tags: html, css

I am creating an interface and I am unable to figure out as to why there is a huge gap between the names on the left side being displayed.

I have not set any kind of padding or any margin for any of the html elements. 
I need the three blocks displayed to come within the specified height and not exceed its contents. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cameronspear.com/downloads/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <style>
            .jumbotron {
                padding: 0.5em 0.6em;
                h1 {
                    font-size: 2em;
                }
                p {
                    font-size: 1.2em;
                    .btn {
                        padding: 0.5em;
                    }
                }
            }

            .menuItem {
                background-color: #e0e0ff;
                width:295px;
                height:183px;
                border:2px solid #000;
            }

            .fontSize {
                color: #00000;
                font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; 
                font-size: 200%; 
                text-align: center;
            }
            .menuItem:hover { -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc; 
                              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 50px #ccc; 
            } 
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h2 style="text-align:center;">Head And Neck Therapy </h2>
            </div>

            <div style="width:1140px; height: 550px;border:2px solid #000;">
                <div style="width:300px; height: 550px;display: inline-block"> 
                        <a href="#"> <div class="menuItem fontSize"> Scan Images </div> </a>
                        <a href="#"><div class="menuItem fontSize"> Patient Details </div> </a>
                        <a href="#"><div class="menuItem fontSize"> Confirmation  </div> </a>
                    </div>
                <div style="width:832px; height: 548px;display: inline-block"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the menu items in a float left div:

```
    <div style="width:1140px; height: 550px;border:2px solid #000; background-color: blue">
        <div style="float: left">
            <div style="width:300px; height: 550px;display: inline-block; background-color: red"> 
                <a href="#"> <div class="menuItem fontSize"> Scan Images </div> </a>
                <a href="#"><div class="menuItem fontSize"> Patient Details </div> </a>
                <a href="#"><div class="menuItem fontSize"> Confirmation  </div> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="width:832px; height: 548px;display: inline-block; background-color: green">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I need that empty div as well. I will have to insert other elements in that specific div.

Comment: ok, and the empty div will display content to the right of the menu items?

Comment: Thank you so much ! This totally solved my problem. What exactly was I doing wrong though ?

Comment: not sure, maybe the browser could not fit all elements into the containing div and got confused.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following URL with the modified code. It might be what you're looking for.  http://liveweave.com/Ci6YPG

Answer (score 0):

You have your `menuItem` elements set to `display: inline-block`. That's positioning them based on the `line-height` which you're not setting and would end up being 20px. Try using `display: block` or set the line-height equal to the container's height.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the .menuItem height and div style="width:1140px; height: 550px;". You will get the spaces removed and then accordingly you can give width and height.